# how can i get 2d angle from a 3d quaternion rotation?

Tags: math, 2d, quaternions

I would like to know how can i get 2d angle from a 3d quaternion rotation?
for example I have a 3d skeletal bones and I wanna my 2d sprite follow the rotation from for example Head bone in 2d orthogonal camera.

thanks for answers.

is there any ways?

Comment: Probably you should apply your 3D rotation then perform 2D projection to get the position you want. Not sure why you need an angle - can you perhaps show an example image?

Comment: Thanks @Roger but, I don not have any image i am just testing with LibGDX, it seems I can get by **float angle = (float) (2 * Math.acos(rotation.w));** rotation here is Quaternion, but after the bone rotated more that 180 degree the sprite flips the direction.

Comment: What I was thinking was that you have a pair of 3D coordinates (representing say the endpoints of the bone) that you project to 2D (you get a 2D vector), then you apply the quaternion to the 3D coordinates and project again to 2D (to get another 2D vector). Then use the angle between the first and second 2D vectors to get what you want.

Comment: @Roger this is a somehow a solution like used in OpenGL render system, I found some articles and try to find a good solution. also will test your way, seems reasonable.